# Corda Shell Issue

Tags: corda

When running Corda DemoBench and using the shell I get an error saying. The error I get is when I try to do the run getCashBalance. I am using the Corda on a Mac and I have the latest Java installed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCHq6.jpg)

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are normally facing issues, check the available commands by typing:

**run**

This will display a list of available commands in the Corda shell.

In the Corda shell, run the command  **cash balances** ,for the right command